# Nature Sounds Libraries in HQ: where?

Tags: ambience, sound-quality, nature, loop

can you point me to the best Nature Libraries that include ambience loops in super High Quality?

I mean paid ones .. (so no Freesound or such) .. I need optimum quality and clarity

so far I didn't find any satisfying library - either too complex or quality wasn't that good...

thanks!!

Comment: Your question is rather vague and difficult to answer. The term "super high quality" is rather subjective and really undefined. We don't know what it means to you or why you need it?  We don't know what kinds of sounds you are looking for?  Ambient? Animals? etc.  "Nature" is a pretty broad field. And we don't know what libraries (other than Freesound) you have investigated and rejected (or why).  If you have such very precise requirements, you may be limiting yourself to going out and recording it yourself.

Comment: lol .. I totally see your point .. ok ..narrowing it down: I need to recreate a jungle atmosphere but I need it to be flexible .. (jungle sound beds are usually really complex) so I'm looking for a Nature sound library that includes say separated crickets - separated frogs etc.... all in high quality .. what do I mean by HQ? I simply mean polished and ready to use .. I will record stuff myself for sure but it's not summer yet around here and I can't wait .. I'm looking for such libraries to use them as a place holder sounds .. but I need them to be HQ (as they'll be in the final game)

Answer (score 0):

I went to www.sounddogs.com and they returned 2102 clips when I searched for: jungle

They had 2509 clips for: crickets

And 1027 for: frogs

They are a combination of several large SFX libraries in hollywood used by feature films, TV, games, etc.

Comment: thanks Richard! .. knew the site but that's the thing: when I click on the preview they sound like crap lol..  far from being pristine HQ recordings .. and being, what I need atm, just place-holder sounds I don't want to "waste" time tweaking those sounds if that makes sense.. I assume those previews are downgraded in quality but before I buy anything I need to evaluate it ;) ... for now www.prosoundlibraries.com seems to be the best fit tho'